# Authorization header in a GET request in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

It seems impossible to accomplish a GET request that requires HTTP Authentication in ActionScript?

Answer (score 3):

ya unfortunately for us all you can not use the authorization header in the Flash player. I'm pretty sure AIR supports it, though that probably doesn't help you. There are lots more headers not allowed, these are listed in the documentation.

The solution is to run your request through a proxy (such as a php script) that executes your request and returns the response. Thus works quite well as your Flash application does not need to be aware of this extra step.

I hope that helps (cause it took forever to type on this phone!)